# Multiplicative linear functional on B* algebra

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a $B^*$ algebra and $\phi$ is a multiplicative linear functional on $B$. Is it true that $\phi(a^*)=\overline{\phi(a)}$? Do we need any additional assumption here? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hint: Write $a=u+iv$ with $u,v$ selfadjoint.

Comment: Thank you @Gerd. I followed your comment. However, I need to show that self-adjoint elements are mapped to real numbers then. I got stuck here.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. If the Banach algebra is commutative then self-adjoint elements are mapped to real numbers. If the Banach algebra is non-commutative it is clear if $a$ is normal but I am not sure about the general situation.

Comment: Thank you @Gerd. However, even if we assume commutativity, how to prove that.

Comment: The spectrum of a self-adjoint element $b$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (see for example here:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071490/self-adjoint-element-of-c-algebra-has-real-spectrum) and for each multiplicative linear functional $\phi$ you have $\phi(b) \in \sigma(b)$.